# how exactly to use foreach in nodejs for Mongodb operations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, foreach, mongojs

This is my code to get the data from a collection groupname which is initialised with the name of collection. I want to iterate the data stored in doc using `foreach` loop.

```
var db = mongojs('login');

    var cursor = db.collection(groupname).find();
    console.log(cursor);

    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        console.log(doc._id);

        mongo.collection(doc._id + "group", function(err, collection) {
            collection.remove({"groupname": groupname});
        });
    });
```

I've tried doing `db.collectionname.find().forEach(....)`, but I've got an error saying that such function doesn't exists. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

The `find()` call to fetch the records from Mongo DB is asynchronous. You are trying to use the docs even before the data is available. You should have your `forEach` loop in the call back of the `find()`.

`

```
db.collection(groupname).find({}, function(err, doc){
console.log(doc);
doc.forEach(function(err,doc){
    console.log(doc._id);
    db=mongo.collection(doc_id+"group");
    db.remove({"groupname":groupname});
});
});
```

`

Comment: I tried using your code. The code executes but nothing happens. The control does not enter the function(err,doc). Any idea why?

Comment: hey I realised where i was going wrong. I was deleting the  collection before it could select the data. Now i get the message on console which shows the value for doc._id as undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **[`each()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each)** method to iterate over all the documents for the **[`find()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#)** cursor:

```
// Grab a cursor
var cursor = db.collection(groupname).find();
console.log(cursor);

// Execute the each command, triggers for each document
cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc._id);
    // Fetch a collection to remove document
    mongo.collection(doc._id + "group", function(err, collection) {
        collection.remove({"groupname": groupname});
    }
});
```

-- **UPDATE** --

Seeing that you are using the **[mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs)** library after your edit, you need to pass a callback function to handle the results of the query since Node.js implements an asynchronous paradigm and almost everything is always a callback which allows your app to be non-blocking and high performing:

```
// connect now, and worry about collections later
var db = mongojs('login')
var groupcollection = db.collection(groupname)

groupcollection.find({}, function(err, groups) {
    if( err || !groups) console.log("No groups found");
    else groups.forEach( function(group) {
        console.log(group);
        mongo.collection(group._id + "group", function(err, collection) {
            collection.remove({"groupname": groupname});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi. I get the following error TypeError: cursor.each is not a function

Comment: @sachinhunur Can you edit your question to include the code where the `db` object is instantiated/initialiased?

Comment: @sachinhunur You did not mention that you are using the mongojs library hence why the above piece of code doesn't work for you.

Comment: How do i make it work with mongojs? I had to use mongojs  wrapper cause find() function was not working

Comment: @sachinhunur I've updated my answer to include the mongojs implementation.

Comment: thanks a lot. your code worked. had to make a one change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685529/how-to-do-find-using-node-and-mongodb .help me out